# invoke broadcast receiver on receiving data sms in android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

i am sending data sms to an emulator through another emulator,My data sms sent there but my `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't get invoked. 
I tried sending/receiving a text SMS and that works absolutely fine but I need to specify a port so only my application can listen for the SMS.

This question has been asked twice but never answered: kindly help me if you know the solution

Receiver.java:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

// Declaration of Variable for getting the message in it    


/*
*Called when The Message Received
*/
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { 
        try{


        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";   
        byte[] data = null;

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS frommm " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";

                data=msgs[i].getUserData();

                for(int index=0; index<data.length; ++index)
                {
                       str += Character.toString((char)data[index]);


                }




            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("The message is "+ str);


        }    
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Menifest file code: (only relevant code)

<  receiver android:name=".Receiver"  >

```
   <  intent-filter  > 

      <  action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" /  >

      <  data android:scheme="sms" /  >

      <  data android:host="localhost"/  >

      <  data android:port="5009"/  >

      <  action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /  >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /  >  

        <  /intent-filter  > 

    <  /receiver  >
```

**permissions :**
    <   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/   >

```
<   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/  >

<  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /     >

<  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/  >
```

Data message sending code:

**message** contains String that i want to send

```
byte []b=message.getBytes();
Short sObj2 = 5009;

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendDataMessage(phoneNumber,null,sObj2,b,sentPI, deliveredPI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1576 it does not appear that data SMS works on an emulator. Did you try the comment #23 from http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1576 on a real device?

Comment: thnxx femi for the reply, i have done that already but my broadcast receiver dont get invoked..:(

Comment: Ah, if you edit your question and include the code for your broadcast receiver, where you generate the notification and your AndroidManifest.xml file we might be able to find what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your receiver?  You need to register your BroadcastReceiver.  Create an IntentFilter and pass it to registerReceiver.

Have you confirmed that the native SMS app is receiving the SMS in the emulator?  If this is the case, that means your SMS is actually being received.  I have never sent an SMS between emulators and have only done this with real devices.  The problem I had was that, prior to registering the receiver, I needed to set the priority for it to be higher than any other app that could possibly respond, including the native SMS app.  You can do it like this:

```
filterSMSReceived.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This will make it get notification before any other app can.